# Chrome Web Inspector shows too many global variables

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, global-variables, web-inspector

I'm beginner+ in javascript and developing, so this might be a question of good practices.

When I build js files, I have a bunch of global vars on top, that I can access anywhere which is fine.

But when I use the Chrome Web Inspector with breakpoints, I can easily see the values of Local vars, but the Global vars are "hidden" within all the transparent « navigator functions/variables ».

See picture : https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKtVu.png

So my question is in 2 steps.

1. Is it possible to hide all the semi-transparent « navigator functions/variables » from this window pane ?
2. Would it make a better file if all my js+vars was « embedded » like 
   function AllMyFile(){
   var blah blah blah
   function…
   }
   AllMyFile()

Advice welcome here :)

Comment: My code looks like var Array; function Name(){ var MyLocalVar = … } would it be better to make it AllMyFile(){ var Array; function Name(){ var MyLocalVar = … }… } AllMyFile()

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you provided some code examples. Based on the image I'm not sure if I understand what you mean by hidden variables.  However, its basically understood that all data in javascript is available to the client / users. If you have some reason users from accessing data then consider writing parts of your code in PHP and retrieve it through AJAX.

Comment: Thanks, no, i'm not trying to hide anything, except to "clean" my view while debugging. All the navigator/environment info (infinity, analyser info, node whatever) just clutters the view and makes it hard to read the "global" variables I put (ArrayA…) Most

Comment: btw, I sometimes use "watch expressions", but that implies you already know what you're looking for, as a well trained dev, which I'm not. I'm the worst example of self-taught-trial-and-error-coding :/